# Android Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream

Tags: php, android, json, pdo, io

I'm trying to get a data from the database using PDO(I'm noob here)
It's working on my localhost, but when I tried using an actual server, it's not working and i don't know why coz other file is working just fine and i used the same code, just edit some values

here's the java code

```
public class Attendance extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
Button btnSearch;
EditText searchField;
TextView tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5, statVal, loginVal, logoutVal, accVal;
String stat,login,logout,acc;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
String username;
SessionManager session;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactsList;

//private static String url_search_attendance = "http://10.0.3.2/sunshine-ems/attendance_details.php";
private static String url_search_attendance = "http://www.sunshine-ems.balay-indang/mobile/attendance_details.php";
Button btnLogout;
final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.attend);
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    username = session.getUsername();
    //search editText
    searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel();
        }

    };
    searchField.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(Attendance.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });

    //Logout Button
    btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);;
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching All products Activity
            session.logoutUser();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    //Hide TextViews
    instanciateAndHideTextViews();

    // Search Button
    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);      
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new getAttendanceDetails().execute();
            displayTextViews();
        }
    });


}

private void instanciateAndHideTextViews(){

            tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            statVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statVal);
            loginVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginVal);
            logoutVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logoutVal);
            accVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accVal);

            tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tv4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tv5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            statVal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loginVal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            logoutVal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            accVal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void displayTextViews(){
    tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tv4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tv5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    statVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    loginVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    logoutVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    accVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void updateLabel() {

    String myFormat = "yyy-MM-dd"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    searchField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    searchField.requestFocus();
    searchField.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}

private class getAttendanceDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Attendance.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading Attendance details");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("loading....");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                    params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", searchField.getText().toString().trim()));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_search_attendance, "GET", params1);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Details Attendance", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt("success");
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received attendance details
                        JSONArray jsonobj = json.getJSONArray("attendance_data"); // JSON Array

                        // get first object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject a_details = jsonobj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // Setter
                        stat = a_details.optString("status");
                        login = a_details.optString("login_time");
                        logout = a_details.optString("logout_time");
                        acc = a_details.optString("accumulated_time");

                    }else{

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonArray) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                statVal.setText(stat);
                loginVal.setText(login);
                logoutVal.setText(logout);
                accVal.setText(acc);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

}

here's the php code

```
  <?php 
require("config.php");
if (isset($_GET['username'])) {

$query = "
SELECT * FROM attendance
 where username= :username && date= :date";

$query_params = array(':username' => $_GET['username'],
                      ':date' => $_GET['date']
    );

//execute query
try {
    $stmt = $db-> prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt -> execute($query_params);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}  


// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
$rows = $stmt -> fetchAll();

if ($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Post Available!";

    $response["attendance_data"] = array();

    foreach($rows as $row) {

        $a_data = array();
        $a_data["login_time"] = $row["login_time"];
        $a_data["logout_time"] = $row["logout_time"];
        $a_data["accumulated_time"] = $row["accumulated_time"];         
        $a_data["status"] = $row["status"];           


        //update our repsonse JSON data
        array_push($response["attendance_data"], $a_data);
    }

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "You don't have appointment history.";
    die(json_encode($response));
}


}
?>
```

Here's the error log

```
02-04 10:17:06.986: E/Buffer Error(2920): Error converting result    java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
02-04 10:17:06.986: W/System.err(2920): org.json.JSONException: No value for attendance_data
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at com.example.androidtablayout.Attendance$getAttendanceDetails.doInBackground(Attendance.java:180)
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at com.example.androidtablayout.Attendance$getAttendanceDetails.doInBackground(Attendance.java:1)
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-04 10:17:06.994: W/System.err(2920):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-04 10:17:06.994: W/System.err(2920):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

again, it's working on my localhost but not in the actual server. i hope someone can help me. thank you so much